# A question on summation notation and Raabe's test

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

So I have a sum
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2\cdot4\cdot...\cdot2n}{5\cdot7\cdot...\cdot(2n+3)}$$
which I thought meant $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2n}{2n+3}$$ which is trivially convergent by the limit test, and by Raabe's Test (which i'm currently practicing). But Taylor and Mann's book says this series is convergent. So I'm assuming These two series are not equivalent. If that is the case, how do I go about testing for convergence using Raabe's Test?

Comment: To get the second sum from the first it looks like you dropped a lot of terms out with no justification.  Those are definitely not the same sum.

Comment: that makes sense. How should I approach the problem then? Just put it into the form of $\frac{U_{n+1}}{U_n}$ and cancel the terms?

Comment: What is the pattern in the bottom of the first sum?  Did you maybe mean to write $3\cdot5\cdot7\cdots(2n + 3)$?

Comment: Ah, yes! Fixed now.

Comment: As the series is made by multiplication a natural first try will be to use the ratio test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2n}{2n+3}\tag{1}
$$
diverges because the terms don't tend to $0$.

---

The ratio of the terms of the series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2\cdot4\cdot6\cdots2n}{5\cdot7\cdot9\cdots(2n+3)}\tag{2}
$$
is
$$
\frac{2n}{2n+3}\tag{3}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2n}{2n+3}
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2}{2+3/n}\\
&=1\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}n\left(\frac{2n}{2n+3}-1\right)
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{-3n}{2n+3}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{-3}{2+3/n}\\
&=-\frac32\\
&\lt-1\tag{5}
\end{align}
$$
$(4)$ and $(5)$, by [Raabe's Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test#Raabe.27s_test), indicate convergence.

---

As a check, we can also use the [AM-GM Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means#The_inequality) to show
$$
\sqrt{(2n+2)(2n+4)}\le2n+3\tag{6}
$$
Therefore
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{2\cdot4\cdot6\cdots2n}{\color{#C00000}{5}\cdot\color{#00A000}{7}\cdot\color{#0000FF}{9}\cdots\color{#C08000}{(2n+3)}}
&\le\sqrt{\frac{2\cdot4\cdot6\cdots2n}{\color{#C00000}{4}\cdot\color{#00A000}{6}\cdot\color{#0000FF}{8}\cdots\color{#C08000}{(2n+2)}}}\sqrt{\frac{2\cdot4\cdot6\cdots2n}{\color{#C00000}{6}\cdot\color{#00A000}{8}\cdot\color{#0000FF}{10}\cdots\color{#C08000}{(2n+4)}}}\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{2}{2n+2}}\sqrt{\frac{2\cdot4}{(2n+2)(2n+4)}}\\
&\le\frac{\sqrt2}{(n+1)^{3/2}}\tag{7}
\end{align}
$$
then apply the [$p$-test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_%28mathematics%29#P-series) and comparison test to show that $(2)$ converges.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** You have
$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty a_n$$
where
$$a_n = \frac{2\cdot4\cdots2n}{5\cdot7\cdots(2n+3)}$$
To use Raabe's Test consider the quotient
$$b_n = \frac{a_{n + 1}}{a_n} = \frac{2\cdot4\cdots2(n+1)}{5\cdot7\cdots(2(n+1)+3)}\cdot\frac{5\cdot7\cdots(2n+3)}{2\cdot4\cdots2n} = \frac{2(n + 1)}{2(n + 1) + 3} = \frac{2n + 2}{2n + 5}$$
You have to compute the limit of $b_n$ and of $n(b_n - 1)$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: do you mean $\lim_{n \to \infty} n(1-b_n)$? and also it looks that that would mean the series diverges.

Comment: @Calc1DropOut, Raabe's test requires to calculate $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n(b_n-1)$. Why do you think that the series is divergent?...

Comment: @Ludolila: I see that it's convergent now. But shouldn't it be $\frac{a_{n}}{a_{n+1}}$ then if you write it that way? I guess it's the same, just a different number to test if it's greater than or less than.

Comment: @Calc1DropOut: I'm not sure what you mean... But out of curiosity, I googled it. Here is what wikipedia says: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test#Raabe.27s_test :) . Do you have a different version in mind?

Comment: Looks like they're equal. The one I'm using has convergence if $> 1$ instead of $-1$